# Htaccess Redirection Old Page to New Page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have changed one of my pages' slug, i want to redirect the old one to new one.

What i've written in htaccess file is :

```
Redirect 301 /event.php?event_id=10&slug=old-slug-example http://www.mywebsite.com/event/10/new-slug-example
```

But when i try to reach to old link, browser returns this :

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/event/10/new-slug-example?event_id=10&slug=old-slug-example
```

How can i fix that, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `?` at the end of the redirect target:

```
# here -------------------------------------------v
http://www.mywebsite.com/event/10/new-slug-example?
```

But then you'll end up with an ugly `?` at the end. You could resort to mod_rewrite and it won't show up in the browser's URL address bar:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} event_id=10&slug=old-slug-example
RewriteRule ^/?event.php$ http://www.mywebsite.com/event/10/new-slug-example? [L,R=301]
```