# How to redirect old page address to new page address on same domain using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-2

I have changed one of my pages' Baby Care, i want to redirect the old one to new one.

What i've written in htaccess file is :

```
    Redirect 301 /babycare/article/category/14 /babycare/article/category/Baby_Care
```

but this results as

```
    http://localhost/babycare/article/category/Baby_Care?/article/category/14
```

i've applied [Jon Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851273/jon-lin) answer to the question [htaccess-redirection-old-page-to-new-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753745/htaccess-redirection-old-page-to-new-page) now my url look like

```
    http://localhost/babycare/article/category/Baby_Care?
```

but i'm unable to remove ? at the end, how can i fix. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I've found my answer just restructure code like this

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /babycare/article/category/14 [NC] 
    RewriteRule ^/?(babycare)? /babycare/article/category/Baby_Care? [R=301,L]
```

and finally I get url in address bar as

```
    http://localhost/babycare/article/category/Baby_Care
```